# Modify script so only empty fields are changed in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser

I currently use a script that converts the integer in OBJECTID to a string and combines it with another string (in this case UAW,) to populate a field

```
Field = str(!OBJECTID!) + "UAW"
```

Now that I have populated my fields how can I modify my script so only empty fields are changed moving forward?

I am using the Python Parser in Calculate Field of ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Empty fields read as `None`-- set your new value if the current value is None, otherwise set it to the current value.

```
Field = str(!OBJECTID!) + "UAW" if !Field! is None else !Field!
```

Comment: Mike thank you for the response, but I am getting a syntax error when I copy over to code block in ArcPro. It is flagging the space after the last exclamation point as Invalid Syntax.

Comment: I don't have access to Pro, but you shouldn't need to use the "pre-logic" code block at all since that's a single liner.  it works fine using the main expression box in 10.3, at least